# Collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status *** [.pio/build/nodemcuv2/firmware.elf] Error 1

Tags: visual-studio-code, platformio

I want to use ESP32 for my app. When I compile this code with PlatformIO I get the following error:

```
  [env:nodemcuv2]
platform = https://github.com/Jason2866/platform-espressif32.git#feature/arduino-idf-v4.4
board = nodemcu-32s
framework = arduino
monitor_speed = 115200
```

I get this Error:

```
    |-- <ESP32 BLE Arduino> 2.0.0
Building in release mode
Linking .pio/build/nodemcuv2/firmware.elf
/Users/juliusschmid/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa32/bin/../lib/gcc/xtensa-esp32-elf/8.4.0/../../../../xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio/build/nodemcuv2/firmware.elf] Error 1
```

I don't understand why I get this error message. Can someone help me and explain easily how I can fix the error?